# How to count how many times is finished function in django?

Tags: python, django, count

I have created a function in Django with the purpose that users download files after they fill some form. I want to count how many times is downloaded a file, now how many times is called function. And I want to show that number on my site. How do I do this?

This is my function...

```
def Only(request):
    page_title = 'Title'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            newdoc = request.FILES['file']
            #some tasks

            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = Form()
    return render(request, 'only.html', { 'form': form, 'page_title':page_title })
```

Comment: Would suggest using Django models to store this data. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/ Tutorials for how to do this can be found around the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new integer field in the table where the information of this form is saved. Then when someone fills the form and downloads the file you should update it with +1.

To show this field, first you should create a new post (or get) method to get the field value, and then, you should call this method when you load the page.

Comment: Do I need to create new url in order to load on page?

Comment: I don´t understand your question.